# How to scroll horizontally in IntelliJ IDEA under Windows?

Tags: windows, scrolling, jre, intellij-idea, usability

I have a touchpad/trackpad I can scroll horizontally with (two-finger scroll) basically anywhere.

Not in IntelliJ IDEA, though. Is there a way to make it work there too?

(I do currently use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+`vertical scroll` to `scroll horizontally`)

Comment: What is you OS ?

Comment: Hey @AntonDozortsev, thanks for your time, it's Windows (8.1)

Comment: It's knowns [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115509), still not fixed...

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have upvoted the issue.

Could you make that an answer so I can accept it? (and perhaps encourage people to upvote that *youtrack* issue)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It's known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115509). And still not fixed.

This case reproducible in all JetBrain's IDEs and only on Windows OS.

Comment: For anyone that arrives here, please upvote on the linked ticket. There's a "thumbs up" on the right side next to the text "voters".